# MySQL Between start of previous month and today

Tags: mysql, date

Current I am grabbing a list of users where their account was created between current date and 1 month ago. However I want to adjust this so it pulls all who registered from the start of last month and current date.

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated) BETWEEN CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE()
```

How can thos be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

[Caution: I haven't actually tried this, but know I've done similar things, so there may be a bit of fiddling needed.]

You can use the function `MONTH()` to extract just the month (and you probably need the year similarly).  You then need to convert it back into a daytime form.  But, this double conversion successfully removes the day and time parts.